# PostgreSQL Advance filtering in SELECT

Tags: postgresql, select, filtering

I would like select specific lines dependind of the value in that case, if that table have 'A' in colon X then select only lines that have 'A', if no 'A' then SELECT only 'B'... same for C ...

EX
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH3Po.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can used In caluse or Not In caluse
IN caluse search value which is in your quote value in your particular column
Not IN caluse search value which is not in your quote value in your particular column

```
Select * from yourtablename 
where X In ('A');
Select * from yourtablename 
where X Not In ('A');
```